# In a markup page, how can i add something to textContent property of an html tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I noticed a XSS vuln I am working to resolve where the jqxGrid will render whatever the cell is.  For example: `<a href="javascript:alert('test');">Hello</a>`.  So my thought was to find a way to resolve this.  I am currently looping over the data for what needs to display, and there is a renderer and a cellsrenderer function you can pass.  My question is:  How do i return a HTML string such that the cell, displays text denoted in argument 6.

I have my own sanitization scripts, and stripping scripts i can apply, but i was thinking i could add the value to the textContent property of an HTML element.  Is this possible to do?

Could i do something like:

```
return "<div text-content='VALUE'></div>";
```

instead of:

```
return "<div>" + value + " </div>";
```

Is there an Angular6+ version of JQXGrid we could utilize, which would benefit from the angular injection policies?

I personally am tempted to just make my own version of this grid, but... it will take too much dev time to accomplish to solve this issue.

Assumption: The server checks for this, and the client does as well. Yet, i know we will still get invalid HTML as such.  That being said, assume the above *value* does contain malicious html/javascript.

Comment: There are plenty of alternatives you can use (primeng, material, etc), but StackOverflow is not really the place for recommending libraries

Comment: Im not here to get a library. I wanted to know if there is a way in JQXGrid to sanitiize, or if through HTML apply the text string i want displayed through the nodes `textContent` node, instead of the HTML node which renders.

Comment: You can use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to sanitize your HTML

Comment: @user184994 i am aware of DomSanitizer, but that is for bypassing the Angular Security Rules.  Though I did just look at the sanitize method, which MAY be a valid option, especially since right now, I am working to develop an Angular Component.  Ill have to read specific examples of sanitize command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the result, you can use the `xmp` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is some HTML</p>
</div>
<xmp>
  <p>This is some HTML</p>
</xmp>
```

You can also add the un-sanitized HMTL to an element and get the textContent or innerText back out, then add that to your page.

```js
let html = "<ol><li>This is some HTML</li><li>And some more</li></ol>";

let unsanitized = document.querySelector('#unsanitized');
let sanitized = document.querySelector('#sanitized');

let tempEl = document.createElement('div');
tempEl.innerHTML = html;

unsanitized.innerHTML = html;
sanitized.innerHTML = tempEl.textContent;
```

```html
<div id="unsanitized"></div>
<div id="sanitized"></div>
```

Comment: Due to the deprecated nature of xml, i would likely want to use `<pre>` instead.  I didnt want to use javascript as much as just do it in pure markup.  Ill take a look at the pre tag which might do what i want.  When trying to do:  `<pre><a href="#">test</a></pre>` it didnt do as i expected.  Ill keep looking into other demos